# Deploy multiple APIs under one customized domain (microservices)

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am really new to Amazon Web Services, so I will write here a lot, because I am not really sure what is causing my problem.

### Introduction

I am trying to deploy microservices application using amazon web services products.My application wouldn't be really big, so I choosed Lambdas as compute "machine" (yeah, it's serverless). Because I have Java background I choosed [this](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-serverless-java-container/tree/master/samples/spring/pet-store) example as my boilerplate.

### Code

What I have done so far is, two simple services, for test purposes:

```
@RestController
@EnableWebMvc
public class PingPong {
    @RequestMapping(path = "/ping", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String ping() {
        return "pong pong pong";
    }
}
```

second one has similar code (the only difference is sentence `pong pong pong 2`).

yamls for my apps are as follow:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: Ping2 application
Resources:
  PingSecondFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: test.view.LambdaHandler::handleRequest
      Runtime: java8
      CodeUri: target/serverless-spring-example-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
      MemorySize: 192
      Policies: AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole
      Timeout: 20
      Events:
        GetResource:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /{proxy+}
            Method: any
```

### What is working on my end

After deployment (both of them) I got two lambdas, and two APIs. So far I was able to execute test on lambdas (they are working nice). I am also able to execute my API via "working" endpoint (.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/Prod/ping) it works.

### Problem

I added custom domain for my APIs:
[image]

and when I am trying to access any of my APIs (api.mydomain.com/ping1/ping), they are dead.

Because of that I decided to take a look at CloudWatch logs, and here is what I can find there:

```
Endpoint request body after transformations: {"resource":"/{proxy+}","path":"/ping1/ping","httpMethod":"GET","headers":
```

Obviously I got 404 for such request.

---

## Major question

How should I deploy my APIs to make them work under one domain?

## Ideal scenario

The configuration of my dream, would be to serve APIs under:

```
mydomain.com/apps/<api-name>/v1/ping
```

I choosed subdomain because under `mydomain.com` I got static content served from S3, and I want to avoid looking up for `/apps` catalog in it - in other words, I wanted to first make my endpoint work under ANY endpoint, and after that start to doctorize on other stuff).

## What I *don't want* to achieve

Of course, I could write my mapping as `@RequestMapping(path = "/ping1/ping")`, but I don't want this solution. The reason is, that I want to keep my services compact (be able to deploy them under any URL without need to change code).

---

#### Miscellenious questions

1. Why I got two stages of API (Prod and Stage) while under both the same content is served. How could I use those stages (Stage for testing, and Prod for tested endpoints)?
2. My APIs are deployed in Frankfurt zone, why I needed to upload certificate in North Virginia?
3. I can't perform test of my API via AWS tool:
   [image]
   I got 500 `"message": "Internal server error"` after performing such test. In logs I can see:

   `Wed Mar 22 19:12:26 UTC 2017 : Endpoint request body after transformations: {"resource":"/{proxy+}","path":"/ping","httpMethod":"GET","headers":null,"queryStringParameters":null,"pathParameters":{"proxy":"ping"},"stageVariables":null,"requestContext":{"accountId":"548199570266","resourceId":"eydd71","stage":"test-invoke-stage","requestId":"test-invoke-request","identity":{"cognitoIdentityPoolId":null,"accountId":"548199570266","cognitoIdentityId":null,"caller":"548199570266","apiKey":"test-invoke-api-key","sourceIp":"test-invoke-source-ip","accessKey":"ASIAJ5ZPFHH6DH42SZTQ","cognitoAuthenticationType":null,"cognitoAuthenticationProvider":null,"userArn":"arn:aws:iam::548199570266:root","userAgent":"Apache-HttpClient/4.5.x (Java/1.8.0_112)","user":"548199570266"},"resourcePath":"/{proxy+}","httpMethod":"GET","apiId":"mckfbehxul"},"body":null,"isBase64Encoded":false}`

How should I perform test to avoid this situation?

Comment: A lot of information here. How do you route your path inside Lambda since Lambda only accepts payload as input?

Comment: I have not change anything in that project, apart endpoints. Here you can find, how Lambda handles request: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-serverless-java-container/blob/master/samples/spring/pet-store/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/serverless/sample/spring/LambdaHandler.java